# Combobox with images and full row select in win api

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to embed a combobox item into my GUI application using Win API. I need the combobox to have images, so it seems that ComboBoxEx does exactly that.

However when using this combobox, if an item is selected only the item text is highlighted, not the "full row". What I would like to have is something like a listviews LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT.

Is this possible using this control? If not which control would be most appropriate for doing this job?

EDIT: Here my code for creation of the combobox:

```
HWND combobox = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOXEX, TEXT(""), CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 100, 300, parentHwnd, (HMENU)1234, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
HICON icon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
HIMAGELIST im_list = ImageList_Create(16, 16, 0, 1, 0);
ImageList_AddIcon(im_list, icon);

COMBOBOXEXITEM it;
it.pszText = L"Test";
it.mask = CBEIF_TEXT | CBEIF_IMAGE | CBEIF_SELECTEDIMAGE;
it.iItem = 0;
it.iIndent = 0;
it.iImage = 0;
it.iSelectedImage = 0;
SendMessage(combobox, CBEM_INSERTITEM, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&it));
SendMessage(combobox, CB_SETCURSEL, 0, 0);
SendMessage(combobox, CBEM_SETIMAGELIST, 0, (LPARAM)im_list);
```

Which unfortunatly doesn't show the desired behavior.

Comment: It must be possible: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404152(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ComboBoxEx will do this. You don't need to write your own owner-drawing code. If I remember correctly, it worked for me out of the box. You just set an ImageList, and then when adding items, make sure to set the mask to `CBEIF_TEXT | CBEIF_IMAGE | CBEIF_SELECTEDIMAGE` and set the appropriate fields. I can't tell what you're doing wrong, since you didn't post your code.

Comment: Hi, yes with owner-drawn controls, but I wounder whether I can do it using some standard control without using owner drawn stuff.
I edited my post and show some code. The combobox itself is shown correct and the image is also displayed. However, only the text is selected not the whole row.

Comment: strange, in my test this code working well with full row select. visual styles is enabled by manifest ?

Comment: Hi, well I tried it with and without the linker directive for visual styles, but it didn't change anything...

Comment: If I embed a manifest that enables Visual Styles (by explicitly opting in to the use of v6 of the common controls), your code works for me.

Comment: I investigated this further and it seems that the problem is I create the window from within a dll and the calling process itself has no visual styles enabled, so enabling it when compiling the dll only doesn't enable it for the calling process... I suspect that without visual styles there is no inbuilt control for the "old" styles that has full row select, right? (I actually want to use the old style fixed regardless of the window theme)

Answer (score 0):

This working code does what you ask, VS 2017, c++.
You have to create some bitmaps and dialog as explained below and you are set to go.

```
// List image Icon Test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

// READ ME:
// Create a new c++ desktop application
// Remove all the code from the cpp section and insert all this code.
// Create a dialog in VS editor, which has a list box called IDLIST and a combobox called IDCOMBO
// it will already have ok and cancel buttons these can stay.
// Create 4 bitmaps any size, only 24x24 will be shown and put them in the source project directory,
// eg C:\Users\Pts1\source\repos\List image Icon Test\List image Icon Test
// Rename the bitmaps Black.bmp, Blue.bmp, Red.bmp, Green.bmp and make sure they are of the format bmp not just called bmp.
// or ideally create the bitmaps so that they are 24x24 and all black,blue etc
// add IDB_Bread bitmap to the editor or remove them from the code below as instructed. We can load bitmaps directly from file instead.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List image Icon Test.h"
#include "strsafe.h"

#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='Win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

#define ID_BREAD 0
#define ID_DAIRY 1
#define ID_FRUIT 2
#define ID_MEAT  3

#define CX_BITMAP 24
#define CY_BITMAP 24

HBITMAP hbmBread, hbmDairy, hbmMeat, hbmFruit, hbmMask, hbmIcon;

HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void InitGroupList(HWND hDlg);
void DeleteIconBitmaps(void);
BOOL LoadIconBitmaps(void);
void InitFoodList(HWND hDlg);
INT_PTR CALLBACK FoodDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_LISTIMAGEICONTEST, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow)) return FALSE;

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_LISTIMAGEICONTEST));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_LISTIMAGEICONTEST));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_LISTIMAGEICONTEST);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hWnd, FoodDlgProc);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


// Message handler for Square Meal dialog box. Click on Help -> ABout Box to activate this dialog.
// You must set the combo box properties to these for this to work.
//
// !!!!!   The combo box you create for this example uses the CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED, (optional)CBS_SORT, CBS_HASSTRINGS, WS_VSCROLL, and (optional) WS_TABSTOP styles. !!!!!!
//

INT_PTR CALLBACK FoodDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    TCHAR achTemp[256];
    HWND hwnd;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:

        // Call an application-defined function to load bitmap resources.
        if (!LoadIconBitmaps())
        {
            Beep(2000, 250);
            EndDialog(hDlg, -1);
            break;
        }

        // Initialize the food groups combo box and select the first item.
        InitGroupList(hDlg);
        SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDCOMBO, CB_SETCURSEL, 0, 0);

        // Initialize the food list box and select the first item.
        InitFoodList(hDlg);
        SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDLIST, LB_SETCURSEL, 0, 0);

        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_MEASUREITEM:
    {
        // Set the height of the items in the food groups combo box.
        LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpmis = (LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

        if (lpmis->itemHeight < CY_BITMAP + 2) lpmis->itemHeight = CY_BITMAP + 2; 

    }
    break;

    case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        COLORREF clrBackground;
        COLORREF clrForeground;
        TEXTMETRIC tm;
        int x;
        int y;
        HRESULT hr;
        size_t cch;

        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

        if (lpdis->itemID == -1) // Empty item)
            break;

        // Get the food icon from the item data.
        hbmIcon = (HBITMAP)lpdis->itemData;

        // The colors depend on whether the item is selected.
        clrForeground = SetTextColor(lpdis->hDC,
            GetSysColor(lpdis->itemState & ODS_SELECTED ?
                COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT : COLOR_WINDOWTEXT));

        clrBackground = SetBkColor(lpdis->hDC,
            GetSysColor(lpdis->itemState & ODS_SELECTED ?
                COLOR_HIGHLIGHT : COLOR_WINDOW));

        // Calculate the vertical and horizontal position.
        GetTextMetrics(lpdis->hDC, &tm);
        y = (lpdis->rcItem.bottom + lpdis->rcItem.top - tm.tmHeight) / 2;
        x = LOWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits()) / 4;

        // Get and display the text for the list item.
        SendMessage(lpdis->hwndItem, CB_GETLBTEXT,
            lpdis->itemID, (LPARAM)achTemp);


        hr = StringCchLength(achTemp, 256, &cch);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            // TODO: Write error handler.
        }


        ExtTextOut(lpdis->hDC, CX_BITMAP + 2 * x, y,
            ETO_CLIPPED | ETO_OPAQUE, &lpdis->rcItem,
            achTemp, (UINT)cch, NULL);

        // Restore the previous colors.
        SetTextColor(lpdis->hDC, clrForeground);
        SetBkColor(lpdis->hDC, clrBackground);

        //  Draw the food icon for the item. 
        HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(lpdis->hDC);
        if (hdc == NULL)
            break;

        SelectObject(hdc, hbmMask);
        BitBlt(lpdis->hDC, x, lpdis->rcItem.top + 1,
            CX_BITMAP, CY_BITMAP, hdc, 0, 0, SRCAND);

        SelectObject(hdc, hbmIcon);
        BitBlt(lpdis->hDC, x, lpdis->rcItem.top + 1,
            CX_BITMAP, CY_BITMAP, hdc, 0, 0, SRCPAINT);

        DeleteDC(hdc);

        // If the item has the focus, draw the focus rectangle.
        if (lpdis->itemState & ODS_FOCUS) DrawFocusRect(lpdis->hDC, &lpdis->rcItem);


    }
    break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDCOMBO:
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_SELENDOK)
            {
                InitFoodList(hDlg);
                SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDLIST,
                    LB_SETCURSEL, 0, 0);
            }
            break;

        case IDLIST:
            if (HIWORD(wParam) != LBN_DBLCLK)
                break;

            // For a double-click, process the OK case. 
        case IDOK:

            // Get the text for the selected list item. 
            hwnd = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDLIST);

            // Here it is assumed the text can fit into achTemp.
            // If there is doubt, call LB_GETTEXTLENGTH first.
            SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETTEXT,
                SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0),
                (LPARAM)achTemp);

            // TODO: Do something with the selected text.

            EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
            break;

        case IDCANCEL:
            hwnd = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDCOMBO);
            if (SendMessage(hwnd, CB_GETDROPPEDSTATE, 0, 0))
                SendMessage(hwnd, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, FALSE, 0);
            else EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:

        // Call the application-defined function to free the bitmap resources.
        DeleteIconBitmaps();
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

// Loads string resources and adds them as items to the drop-down list of
//   the food groups combo box. The bitmap handle of each item&#39;s icon is
//   stored as item data for easy access when the item needs to be drawn.
// 
void InitGroupList(HWND hDlg)
{
    TCHAR achTemp[256];
    DWORD dwIndex;

    // Get the handle of the food groups combo box.
    HWND hwndGroupsBox = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDCOMBO);

    LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
    dwIndex = SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);
    SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_SETITEMDATA, dwIndex, (LPARAM)hbmBread);

    LoadString(hInst, IDS_DAIRY, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
    dwIndex = SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);
    SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_SETITEMDATA, dwIndex, (LPARAM)hbmDairy);

    LoadString(hInst, IDS_FRUIT, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
    dwIndex = SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);
    SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_SETITEMDATA, dwIndex, (LPARAM)hbmFruit);

    LoadString(hInst, IDS_MEAT, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
    dwIndex = SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);
    SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_SETITEMDATA, dwIndex, (LPARAM)hbmMeat);

    return;
}

// Fills the food list based on the selected item in the food groups combo box.
void InitFoodList(HWND hDlg)
{
    TCHAR achTemp[256];

    HWND hwndGroupsBox = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDCOMBO);
    HWND hwndFoodList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDLIST);

    // Clear the list contents.
    SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);

    // Find out which food group is selected.
    int idFoodGroup = SendMessage(hwndGroupsBox, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);

    switch (idFoodGroup)
    {
    case ID_BREAD:
        LoadString(hInst, IDS_OATS, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_WHEAT, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_RYE, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);
        break;

    case ID_DAIRY:
        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        break;

    case ID_FRUIT:
        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        break;

    case ID_MEAT:
        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        LoadString(hInst, IDS_BREAD, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        SendMessage(hwndFoodList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)achTemp);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return;
}

// Loads the food icon bitmaps from the application resources.
//
BOOL LoadIconBitmaps(void)
{   
    hbmBread = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(hInst, (wchar_t*) L"Blue.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE); //File has to be of format .bmp
    if (hbmBread != NULL) hbmDairy = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(hInst, (wchar_t*) L"Green.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE); //File has to be of format .bmp
    if (hbmDairy != NULL) hbmMeat = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(hInst, (wchar_t*)L"Red.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE); //File has to be of format .bmp

    /*
    // original code which still works, you need to put in bitmaps into the editor itself. eg IDB_Bread, IDB_DAIRY, are 48x48 bitmaps in my editor by default.
    hbmBread = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BREAD));
    if (hbmBread != NULL) hbmDairy = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_DAIRY));
    if (hbmDairy != NULL) hbmMeat = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_Green));
    */

    if (hbmMeat != NULL) hbmFruit = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BREAD)); //Bitmap defined in the editor(resource.h) which calls a Black.bmp file. See VS Bitmap editor.
    if (hbmFruit != NULL) hbmMask = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BREAD));

    if (hbmMask != NULL)
        return TRUE;


    return FALSE;
}

// Frees the icon bitmps.
//
void DeleteIconBitmaps(void)
{
    FreeResource(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(hbmBread));
    FreeResource(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(hbmDairy));
    FreeResource(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(hbmMeat));
    FreeResource(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(hbmFruit));
    FreeResource(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(hbmMask));
}
```